# Find out the longest path being alive

Tags: mathematics, optimization, computer-puzzle

Start from any integer. Move horizontally or vertically (not diagonally), and if you come across the same integer more than once you will die. Moving diagonally is not allowed. What is the longest path where you will end up alive?

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 8 | 18 | 15 | 24 | 20 | 2 | 20 |
| 6 | 2 | 15 | 2 | 17 | 15 | 3 | 7 |
| 0 | 11 | 18 | 16 | 20 | 15 | 1 | 11 |
| 6 | 2 | 6 | 13 | 4 | 17 | 20 | 16 |
| 5 | 12 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 18 | 23 |
| 7 | 13 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 11 | 4 | 23 |
| 16 | 23 | 10 | 2 | 4 | 12 | 5 | 10 |
| 17 | 12 | 10 | 1 | 13 | 12 | 6 | 20 |

I tried figuring out the possible ways where I do not die but I was not able to do this. Is there any trick or logic to find the longest path?

My longest path is 6 8 18 15 24 17 20 4 3 2 11 12 5 10 23

Comment: Do you have an answer to this question or are you just trying to check your answer?

Comment: I don't have any proper approch to solve this tricky puzzle , I just solving this like a layman .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no proper "solution" to this problem in general - it borders on many things known in computer science to be numerically solvable but in a brute force way.

So, then, two approaches:

> Semi-manual attempts with conditional formatting in excel automatically crossing out the numbers I've already visited was where I started. Was not much more successful than you were.

> Then I went full in and wrote a slightly modified version of your typical maze solver (depth-first search, just finds all the possible paths instead of terminating upon reaching the exit and an additional condition of not repeating numbers). Here is the answer: [image: resulting path] It is of length 20.

Answer (score 6):

I have found the result as starting from

> the 1 located bottom of the table

and

> 13,1,10,12,23,16,7,5,6,0,11,2,8,18,15,24,17,20,4,3

which makes the length of the route as

> 20

First, I have located the rarest numbers ( the ones used only once);

> 0,8,24

then the rest seems easier than I thought by eliminating numbers which are inbetween these three numbers:

> 11,2,18,15

This solution is optimal since there are 20 distinct numbers and I passed on all of them.

Comment: There are only 20 distinct numbers.

Comment: You repeat 13 and 28 should be read as 18 (2, 8, 18, ...)

Comment: you guys are right, edited accordingly, seems I am at 19. one is missing in the list.

Comment: You are so very close, apparently :) I will post a computer-assisted solution shortly.

Comment: There is a 13 next to your starting point. See if you can use it while avoiding the other.

Comment: Isn't it just hit and trial? That is bit downside of this puzzle, I'd rather prefer puzzles with concrete solutions.

Comment: @I'mNobody to be honest, it is not much, since the answer exists by using all numbers at the end.